# Why do we use the word "kernel" in the expression "Gaussian kernel"?

Tags: machine-learning, terminology, math, history, support-vector-machine

I've heard the expression "Gaussian kernel" in several contexts (e.g. in the kernel trick used in SVM). A [Gaussian kernel](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/17352/10640) usually refers to a [Gaussian function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_function) (that is, a function similar to the probability density function of a [Gaussian distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution)) that is used to measure the similarity between two vectors (or numbers).

Why is this Gaussian function called a "kernel"? Why not just calling it a Gaussian (similarity) function? Does it have something to do with the [kernel of a linear transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(algebra))?

Comment: I believe we use the word kernel because we are transforming the basis.

Answer (score 1):

The usage of the word "kernel" in the context of support vector machines probably comes from its usage in the context of [integral transforms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_transform).

See the article [Kernel of an integral operator](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Kernel_of_an_integral_operator), and the questions [What is the difference between a kernel and a function?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/22133/168764) and [Why is the kernel of an integral transform called kernel?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1919305/168764).

The word "kernel" has been used in many other contexts, such as in computer vision, to refer to a certain function with a special purpose. See e.g. the paper that introduced [SIFT](https://www.cs.ubc.ca/~lowe/papers/ijcv04.pdf).